# Asynchronous ng-click/change/submit Event Handlers

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise, angular-http

I have the following code:

in the html template, a `ng-click` is linked to a function `deleteFile`:

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files track by $index">
    <a ng-click="deleteFile(file)">delete</a>
</div>
```

in the controller, the function `deleteFile` calls another function `codeService.deleteFile` which contains asynchronous elements:

```
$scope.deleteFile = function (file) { 
    var index = $scope.files.indexOf(file);
    if (index > -1) $scope.files.splice(index, 1);

    codeService.deleteFile(file)
};
```

in `codeService.deleteFile`, it has an asynchronous call `$http`, `then` which contains synchronous code.

```
this.deleteFile = function (file) {
    return $http.post('/rmFile', { dir: prefix + idP + "/", file: file })
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log("codeService, physical deleteFile, done: " + res.data.name);
            var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe'); 
            iframe.src = iframe.src
        })
}
```

People say [when using promise always return](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39655869/702977), I would like to know what's the **best practice** to organise these async-sync-mixed code. Precisely, I have some questions for example,

1. should I return something in the controller? Eg, `return` before `codeService.deleteFile(file)`?
2. should I return something inside `function (res) { ... }` of the `codeService`?
3. when a html template contains several `ng-click`, `ng-change`, `ng-submit` with asynchronous elements, is each `ng-` blocking? If not, if we click/change/submit very fast, that would be messy, no?

Comment: 1) yes, return the promise 2) yes, return `res` (i.e. pass through)

Comment: Angular event handlers are single-threaded but non-blocking for asynchronous operations. If click/change/submit events happen very fast, that would be messy, yes. It is worth considering disabling the other input elements until the asynchronous operation completes either fulfilled or rejected. Consider using the [ng-disabled directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular event handlers are single-threaded but non-blocking for asynchronous operations. If click/change/submit events happen very fast, that would be messy, yes. It is worth considering disabling the input elements until the asynchronous operation completes either fulfilled or rejected. Consider using the [ng-disabled directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).

```
<button ng-click="decrease()" ng-disabled="wait">Decrease</button>
<p ng-show="wait" style="color: red">Processing</p>
```

#### JS

```
vm.decrease = function() {
    vm.wait = true;
    return $http.delete("url").then( function(response) {
      vm.quantity--;
      vm.wait = false;
      return response;
    }).catch( function(errorResponse) {
      vm.wait = false;
      throw errorResponse;
    });
};
```

In the above example, the click handler immediately sets the `wait` flag `true`. It then resets the flag when the XHR completes either fulfilled or rejected. When the wait flag is `true` the input is disabled and a <kbd>Processing</kbd> message appears.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/cKCVRGpx2QupDTzB3EXs?p=preview)

---

#### Asynchronous Validators with the ngModelController

The ngModelController sets a `$pending` flag that can be used to disable inputs when an asychronous validation is in progress.

For more infomation, see [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference - $asyncValidators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$asyncValidators)

---

> *do you have any comment about my questions 1 & 2?*

The rule of thumb in functional programming is **always return something**.

In the case of promises, if the rejection handler omits both a return and a throw statement, the chained promise will **convert** from a rejection to a fulfilled promise which resolves with a value of `undefined`. A common cause of bugs especially in http interceptors.

Failure to return a nested promise will result in a parent promise resolving before the nested promise completes. Another common cause of bugs.

Failure to return a value to a function in a `.then` method results in the new derived promise resolving to `undefined`. Yet another common cause of bugs.

On the other hand, some people with delicate fingers believe that one should only type the six letters 
<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you... do you have any comment about my questions `1` & `2`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to structure your code

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files track by $index">
    <a ng-click="deleteFile(file)">delete</a>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.deleteFile = function (file) { 
    var index = $scope.files.indexOf(file);
    if (index > -1) $scope.files.splice(index, 1);

    codeService.deleteFile(file).then(function(response){
        console.log("codeService, physical deleteFile, done: " + res.data.name);
    }, function(err){
        console.log("codeService, physical deleteFile, FAIL: " + res.data.name);
    });
};
```

**SERVICE**

```
this.deleteFile = function (file) {
    return $http.post('/rmFile', { dir: prefix + idP + "/", file: file });
}
```

**Answers**

1. You do not have to return something inside your controller function if it is not needed.
2. Inside the success function of `then` you may actually remove the line. Then if you have an error, the line won't be deleted and you can display an error message
3. If your async call take times and you can click multiple times, it can be messy. The call will be done multiple times and you will try to delete same items multiples times. A solution would be to disabled the button when it is clicked (first line inside `$scope.deleteFile`) or add a loading somewhere. You need to block user from clicking 2 times

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear... In `codeService.deleteFile`, I have some sync code in `then` of `$http`, I want to keep that, and don't know what to return...

Comment: I may call some private functions of `codeService`, or, update/refresh the html page: `var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe'); iframe.src = iframe.src;`

Comment: You can still put this code inside `then()` in your controller

Comment: But why would we prefer moving these sync elements from the service to the controller?

Comment: It will be simpler. What if you need to use `codeService.deleteFile` in another controller but you have to do different action when it is done. The `deleteFile` will just delete the file that's it.

Comment: I think what i am after is **what will happen if we 1) return a value 2) does not write return in `function (res) { ... }` of the `codeService`**.

Comment: If you return a value, the code will be stopped after the return. But the returned value is never used. You do not need to return something

Comment: Regarding my question `3`, so `ng-click/submit/change` is NOT blocking? If we click then submit, angular does NOT make sure everything  of `ng-submit` has finished before `ng-submit`?

Comment: you should use catch and finally function for promises. to make something if your promise is resolved or not. it's not a responsibility of angular